# Let $S=X(u,v)$ be a regular surfaces s.t. its coordinate curves are orthogonal. Compute its Gauss equation.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S=X(u,v)$ be a regular surfaces s.t. its coordinate curves are ortogonal, i.e., F=0. Show that

$$K=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left(\left(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_v+\left(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_u\right).$$

Is there a simpler way than expanding the RHS and using that $$F=0\Leftrightarrow \Gamma^1_{22}+\Gamma^2_{12}=\Gamma^1_{11}+\Gamma^2_{11}=0?$$

Comment: This is a long computation where you must be careful with quotient rule and algebra. Start with the Gauss equation on the left, start with rewriting the write ... and eventually make the two agree.

Comment: Right, not write :)

Comment: One more hint: There are reasonably convenient formulas for the $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ when $F=0$. You'll need all those along with the Gauss equation.